# Add a UIImage as Material to a SCNGeometry in ARKit with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Adding a image as material to a predefined 3d object like a Cube in Swift works fine for me. Now I'm trying to add a image as material to a polygone created dynamically on runtime.

I hoped something like this would work:

```
let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

var data = [Int32]()
for (index, value) in vertices.enumerated() {
    data.append(Int32(index))
}
data.insert(Int32(vertices.count), at: 0)

let indexData = Data(bytes: data, count: data.count * MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: .polygon, primitiveCount: 1, bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
if let material = geometry?.firstMaterial {
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage( named: "Diffuse" )
    material.isDoubleSided = true
}
```

when i change the UIImage to UIColor it works fine.
I suggest, that I need a UV Map for the texture. Is it possible to generate something on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i was going about adding images as SCNMaterials

```
var imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
imageMaterial.isDoubleSided = false
imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage")
var cube: SCNGeometry? = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
var node = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
node.geometry?.materials = [imageMaterial]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible and doable for polygons or a collection of polygons, i.e. a mesh, that are based on a formula or are simple. For example, for a single polygon that is a triangle or square or circle etc, or a cube or sphere etc the UV values (a value between 0.0 and 1.0 for each vertex) could be manually entered or calculated. For arbitrary polygons and models it becomes significantly more complex to get a seamless and evenly distributed UV map across multiple polygons.

So the hard part is determining the UV coords, they cannot be automatically generated. But once you determined or even computed the UV coordinates, you can add them by adding a second SCNGeometrySource, using the texcoord semantic: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource.semantic/1523762-texcoord